# How to access ext4 type partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, partitioning

I am unable to write to an ext4 type partition on my external SD Card that I intend to use on my android device. The options in the permissions tab are greyed out. How can I acesss the partition and write to it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run as **root** ? If the partition was not writable, probably the device is mounted as read-only, or you don't have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

Please see any of the numerous Internet tutorials on Unix/Linux ownership and permissions, such as:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm
- http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml
- http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Those are simply some of the first hits that I got in a Web search. (The last one looks like the best for a beginner, at first glance.)

Basically, you need to change the ownership and/or permissions on the disk device, and possibly one or more of its subdirectories, when it is mounted. Thereafter you should be able to write as a normal user.

Note, though, that Linux stores username information as user ID (UID) *numbers.* This is true for both Ubuntu and Android. This is important because the UID number used by Ubuntu (1000 for the first user, by default) might not match what Android uses. (I don't know what Android's default is, offhand.) The same is true for group ID (GID) values. Thus, you may need to set very lax permissions on the device's root directory, and on any shared subdirectories, if you're going to be able to write to it from both devices. Alternatively, you may need to coordinate your UID and/or GID values across your OSes. For all its problems, FAT can be easier for such cross-device applications. FAT doesn't support ownership or permissions, so Linux assigns ownership to whoever mounts the device, which makes ownership and permissions problems go away in many cases. OTOH, sometimes you need these features.